# pandas: create a new dataframe from existing columns values

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this;

```
ID          code   num
333_c_132   x       0
333_c_132   n36     1
998_c_134   x       0
998_c_134   n36     0
997_c_135   x       1
997_c_135   n36     0
```

From this I have to create a new dataframe like below; you can see a new column `numX` is formed with unique `ID`. Please note that `numX` values are taken from `num` column corresponding to `n36`.

```
ID          code   num   numX
333_c_132   x       0     1
998_c_134   x       0     0
997_c_135   x       1     0
```

How can I do this only using pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a mask then merge after pivotting:

```
m = df['code'].eq('n36')
(df[~m].merge(df[m].set_index(['ID','code'])['num'].unstack()
                              ,left_on='ID',right_index=True))
```

---

```
          ID code  num  n36
0  333_c_132    x    0    1
2  998_c_134    x    0    0
4  997_c_135    x    1    0
```

Comment: i get the following error. **ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape**. any suggestion please.

Comment: @Mass17 you have duplicates in ID and code combination  , try `df[~m].merge(df[m].pivot_table('num','ID','code',aggfunc='first'),left_on='ID',right_index=True)` (*check what aggregation you need depending on your requirement*) basically : for duplicate values in `df[m]` what values you want to keep